# How to setup routes in custom angular library from application

Tags: angular, configuration, angular-library

I want to create a library in order to be able to use it in several applications. The library would be a module that allows you to connect using a portal. I would like to setup configurations to the creation of this module from the application, the configurations must be able to override the route origin (exemple : 'authentification' can be override by 'auth'). So I wrote this module :

```
    { path:  'authentification', component:  StyleRootComponent, children: [
        {
            path:  'portail',
            component:  PortailComponent
        },
        {
            path:  'passwordForgotten',
            component:  PasswordForgotenComponent
        }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [StyleRootComponent, PortailComponent, PasswordForgotenComponent],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes),
        AmplifyAngularModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatCardModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatButtonModule
    ],
    exports: [StyleRootComponent]
})
export class LibraryConnectionModule { 
    static forRoot(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {

        appRoutes[0].path = config.urlAuth;

        return {
            ngModule: LibraryConnectionModule,
            providers: [
            AmplifyService,
            AuthentificationService,
            {
                provide: CognitoConfigsService,
                useValue: config.cognitoConfigs
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

From the application I can just import it

```
imports: [...,
LibraryConnectionModule.forRoot({cognitoConfigs : {}, urlAuth : "auth"}),
...,
]
```

All work like expected with JIT but when I try to build for production (AOT) I got this error :
**ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'

  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'LibraryConnectionModule' was called.**

I know the problem is about this line (I don't really know why) : `appRoutes[0].path = config.urlAuth;`
So in production I can't choose the url to my components from application...
Someone know how I could do that ? (I'm open to any suggestion )

thanks in advance
Max

Answer (score 0):

using this configuration in `tsconfig.json` made the compile error go away and my app and library are now working: I can `loadChlidren` my library's module (which has routing) inside my main app.

```json
"skipTemplateCodegen": true,
"strictMetadataEmit": true,
"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
```

from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23609#issuecomment-386876693
the documentation for those options is here: https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#fulltemplatetypecheck